# Why is GSM interference audible?

Tags: gsm

We have all heard the buzzing sound that your speakers makes when you use your phone near your radio or amp. My question is why does one hear this interference if GSM operates at ~800-900MHz which is 40x higher than the highest humanly audible frequency?

Comment: The answer is convoluted. Ha, get it? Convolution? Ah, forget it.

Comment: @Keagan : more like 40,000-45,000 times the highest audible frequency